# Uncaught Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Cannot render react component. I have created multiple html pages in public folder, index.js file is kept in src folder. I want to render react component in one of the html file inside the bootstrap "row" container. My
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMybt.jpg)

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-mg-6 col-sm-12">
    
          <div id="root"></div>
    
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <script src="../src/index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./Components/App";
    
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
   <StrictMode>
      <App />
   </StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message instead of sending a picture of it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: have you been able to Vitest this code? I get **Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.**

Answer (score 0):

Do not delete root in your html file if u r a beginner.
check for this line  `<div id="root"></div>`
Also checkout this link for more detailed help
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-createroot-target-container-not-dom-element

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34318456)